# Can not run cmdshell @command in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-express, sqlcommand

I can not run cmdshell @command commands in my SQL Server Express. Is it something to do with the SQL Server version? Should I have to have like SQL Server Standard edition to run this command?

Comment: No and no. SQL Server Express has the `xp_cmdshell` feature. If it's not working, you'll have to be more specific about how it's not working. Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission issue which is fixed now! Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Enable it, as described [in the Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option):

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```